# Subtract datetime in python, understanding formats

Tags: python, datetime

Given I have a timestamp:

```
date_time_str = '2019-09-10T13:48:06+0200'
```

How can I calculate the time difference between the current time and this datetime?

I've got it so far with an impression of strong wrongdoing - this should be possible in a far simpler way:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import time

date_time_str = '2019-09-10T13:48:06+0200'
format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, format)

now = datetime.now()
now_time = now.strftime(format)
print(now_time)


now=datetime.strptime(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time.time()), tz=timezone.utc).isoformat(), format)
print("now is: %s" % now)

print(now-time_obj)
```

The above program does not work because the current time comes out in a slightly different formatting:

```
'2019-09-10T15:56:11+00:00'
```

That is, if you run the above script for example Python 3.6.5, you get the error:

```
ValueError: time data '2019-09-10T18:18:09+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
```

The mismatch is in the timezone format, "+00:00" vs. "+0200".

Comment: Can't really reproduce your issue. Can you please be a little bit more specific on what is wrong.

Comment: @SimonFink hi, thank you for your feedback! I've extended the question post. Just run the script and you should see the error.

Comment: python datetime implementation is actually quite cumbersome and not entirely intuitve. Don't feel too dumb lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datetime.now()` to get the current datetime in utc:

```py
# Same as your code
from datetime import datetime, timezone

date_time_str = '2019-09-10T13:48:06+0200'
format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, format)

# Added:
print(datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc))
# 2019-09-10 18:35:48.066548+00:00

print(datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) - date_time_obj)
# 6:47:42.066548
```

Comment: thank you so much,  @Bob! so what I was looking for after all, was the class timedelta and its method .total_seconds()! https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html